# Part of the body won't move fully even when fully painted

Tags: mesh, bones, pose-mode

[image: Hip doesent move with leg]

Hi everyone. As you can see in the picture below i've already painted the hip alongside the leg however when i move the leg the hip moves ever so slightly. Question is how can i make the hip move alot just like the leg? I've also assigned hips vertex group to the leg bone so i'm unsure what to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: hello, please share your file so that we can test: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Ty moonboots! I appreciate all the help i can get!